# What happens to existing function call if useEffect dependency changes before first call is completed?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Lets say i have this :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    asyncCalc(wp);
  }, [value1, value2])

  const asyncCalc = (wp) => {
    if (!start || !end) return
    const service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    service.route(
      {
        origin: start.coordinates,
        destination: end.coordinates,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        waypoints: wp,
        optimizeWaypoints: true
      },
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === "OK" && result) {
          console.log(result)
          setDirections(result);
          waypoint_order.current = result.routes[0].waypoint_order;
          const optimizedRoute = waypoint_order.current.map(index => businessesSelected[index])
          dispatch(setWaypoints(optimizedRoute))
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

If `value1` changes, `asyncCalc` would execute. But what if `value2` changes BEFORE the first call is completed? What happens to that function call.

I kinda tested it with some console.log statements in my `asyncCalc` and it seems to just stop its execution midway. I just want to know if thats true or expected behavior. thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "*before the call is completed*"? What does `expensiveCalc` do? Does it assign to  `value2`? Is it asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: i edited my question for more clarity. i believe its async from how i use it, but im not 100% sure because little docs exist for this starter code from `react-googlemaps-api`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But what if value2 changes BEFORE the first call is completed?

Unless the function has specifically coded something that allows for its interruption mid-process - such as [`AbortController`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AbortController) for `fetch` - *and* your code hooks into that functionality that allows for interruption - then the existing running function will continue on running to the end, without being interrupted.

But, keep in mind:

- `useEffect` callbacks run only after a re-render completes
- If `expensiveCalc` is, as it sounds, *expensive* (rather than *asynchronous*), then if something else tries to call the state setter and cause a re-render, that will only be possible once the expensive function has finished and yielded control back to the rest of the app. JavaScript is single-threaded, so generally speaking, if you have `expensiveCalc(value1, value2);` somewhere in the code, once it starts, that function will go on to the end before any other code can possibly run.

  The code that calls the state setter that could cause the re-render won't even be able to run before the expensive function finishes. Even if it does (say, the expensive function itself calls it), React won't be able to re-render until the current effect hook callback has finished, which requires the expensive function to have completed first.

Comment: i believe my `expensiveCalc` was indeed async. i edited my question for more clarity im not 100% sure because i cant find doc for react-googlemap service api for this direction serivce. if it is async, would it still work the same?

Comment: Still holds - *Unless the function has specifically coded something that allows for its interruption mid-process - such as AbortController for fetch - and your code hooks into that functionality that allows for interruption - then the existing running function will continue on running to the end, without being interrupted.*

Comment: A sync expensive function is impossible to interrupt. An async function is possible to interrupt, to an extent, if it provides the ability to interrupt it.